# iPhoneX not loading @3x images

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, iphone-x

When running my app on an iPhoneX, it is loading my @2x assets instead of my @3x assets. My assets are named using the @2x and @3x convention. From what I read online this might be a bug with spritekit? Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix this?

EDIT: My images are correctly sized at their appropriate scale

All of my images are in Assets.xcassets (asset catalog?) and I load the images using the following:

```
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "image_name")
```

Comment: Does the App know it should run in iphoneX resolution, ie you have an iphoneX launch image or correctly configured storyboard? Check the screen resolution is iphoneX by printing UIScreen.main.bounds in your SKScene.

Comment: Is Zoomed mode active by any chance?

Comment: are your .@2x and .@3x images correct sized in the same asset?  That is .@3x means it is 3 times larger than the asset size, so asset size is 16, .@2x is 32 .@3x is 48

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Yes the images are correctly sized, I forgot to make that clear

Comment: @ChristianCerri I'm kind of new to developing for iPhone X so I'm not 100% sure what you mean by if the app knows it should run in iPhone X resolution I assumed that was something that was done by default. I'm 90% it is using the right resolution because I check for iPhoneX using the height (2436) which seems to be correct

Comment: Are you using regular files for your resources, with the `@2x`/etc naming convention, or Asset Catalog? Does the behavior change if you try the other approach? What API are you loading images with?

Comment: @rickster I edited my answers, thanks for replying though I'm still stumped with this. I believe I'm using the asset catalog, dragging the images wit their @2x/@3x extensions into the appropriate box in the catalog.

Comment: I tried to put together a minimal reproduction of the issue and it's working okay for me... I'd recommend [filing a bug with Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com) and attaching as small/simple a standalone project you can make where you're sure it's running at full screen on iPhone X and not loading your 3x image.

Comment: @rickster Is there a chance I'm not doing this right to begin with? An example of me saving an image would be: Save image.png, image@2x.png, image@3x.png to desktop. Drag image.png into Assets.xcassets. Drag image@2x.png and image@3x.png into the 2x and 3x slot, and then create the image using the code in my answer.

Comment: @Brejuro, that is the correct way.  To make it faster, just drag all 3 images over at the same time. XCode is smart enough to create the proper asset for you.  BTW, how do you know it is using the 2x graphic?  Did you try making a 2x image with a 2x watermark and a 3x image with a 3x watermark to verify what asset is being loaded?

Comment: did you fix it ?